# Why are both of these giving me errors with the variable "testnum"?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

def even_numbers(n1, n2):
# your code here
lst_evennumbers=[]
for x in rang(n1, n2):
testnum=x/2
if type(testnum) == type(int())
lst_evennumbers.append(x)

```
return lst_evennumbers
```

---

def even_numbers(n1, n2):
# your code here
lst_evennumbers=[]

```
for x in rang(n1, n2):
     testnum=x/2
    if testnum % 2 == 0
        lst_evennumbers.append(x)


return lst_evennumbers
```

Comment: Check your indentation **very** carefully

Comment: That and the formatting of your question here. It's effectively unreadable. Also, of course, saying it's "giving me errors" is useless without stating which error that is, so the next one searching for the error message (you did that, right?) can find the answer here. As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Also... **rang**

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Your first problem is that you if statement is done incorrectly. It seems you want to use a ternary if statement which requires an `else` even if you don't want to return anything to be returned otherwise, if you do want an empty else just use a backslash(`\`) after the `else` :

Here is the form of a ternary if stsemnt

```
<var> = n if n == <condition> else \
```

---

Secondly to check if something is even you should check if a division by 2has any remainders(and not if it is an `int`).

**Here is how:**

```
testnum if x % 2 == 0 else \
```

---

**Here is all the corrected code code:**

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2): # your code here
    lst_evennumbers=[] 
    for x in range(n1, n2): 
        testnum = x if x % 2 == 0 else \
        lst_evennumbers.append(x)

    return lst_evennumbers
```

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2): # your code here 
    lst_evennumbers=[]
    for x in range(n1, n2):
        if testnum % 2 == 0:
            lst_evennumbers.append(x)


    return lst_evennumbers
```

---

**Or if you prefer normal if staements:**

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2): # your code here
    lst_evennumbers=[] 
    for x in range(n1, n2): 
        if type(testnum) == int():
            testnum= x/2
        lst_evennumbers.append(x)

    return lst_evennumbers
```

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2): # your code here 
    lst_evennumbers=[]
    for x in range(n1, n2):
        testnum=x/2
        if testnum % 2 == 0:
            lst_evennumbers.append(x)


    return lst_evennumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making following changes in your def even_numbers function:

```
for x in range(n1, n2):
    testnum = x
    if testnum % 2 == 0:
        lst_evennumbers.append(x)


return lst_evennumbers
```

Answer (score -1):

Your range will unnecessarily include odd numbers.

Try this:

```
def even_numbers(n1, n2):
    global lst_evennumbers
    if n1 % 2 != 0:
        n1 += 1
    lst_evennumbers += [e for e in range(n1, n2, 2)]
```